# BDD tests in PHPUnit

Tags: php, php5, bdd, phpunit

No one in my team knows how to write BDD tests, so I started writing some and it's quite working well. I think the time has come to improve the code quality.

This contains a lot of duplicated code and unused features:

```
<?php
require_once ('core/v3/engine.php');
require_once 'PHPUnit/Extensions/Story/TestCase.php';

class cHelperValidationSpec extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Story_TestCase {

    /**
     * Check all the output for the right cases
     * @scenario
     */
    public function specForJobId() {
        $this->given('For a mValue (mixedValue) and we want to validate if it is an integer')
            ->when('sJobId is a positive integer', 123)
            ->then('return of positive integer should be', 'TRUE')
            ->when('sJobId is a negative integer', -123)
            ->then('return of a negative integer should be', 'FALSE')
            ->when('sJobId is a float', 1.23)
            ->then('return of a float should be', 'FALSE')
            ->when('sJobId is a string containing only digits', '123')
            ->then('return of a string (containing only digits) should be', 'TRUE')
            ->when('sJobId is a string containing not only digits', '123abc-?')
            ->then('return of a string (containing not only digits) should be', 'TRUE');
    }

    public function runGiven(&$world, $action, $arguments) {
        switch($action) {
            case 'For a mValue (mixedValue) and we want to validate if it is an integer': {
                $world['helper'] = new cHelperValidation();
            }
            break;

            default: {
                return $this->notImplemented($action);
            }
        }
    }

    public function runWhen(&$world, $action, $arguments) {
        switch($action) {
            case 'sJobId is a positive integer': {}
            case 'sJobId is a negative integer': {}
            case 'sJobId is a float': {}
            case 'sJobId is a string containing only digits': {}
            case 'sJobId is a string containing not only digits': {}
            break;

            default: {
                return $this->notImplemented($action);
            }
        }
    }

    public function runThen(&$world, $action, $arguments) {
        switch($action) {
            case 'return of positive integer should be': {
                $this->assertEquals(TRUE, $world['helper']->isId(123));
            }
            case 'return of a negative integer should be': {
                $this->assertEquals(FALSE, $world['helper']->isId(-123));
            }
            case 'return of a float should be': {
                $this->assertEquals(FALSE, $world['helper']->isId(1.23));
            }
            case 'return of a string (containing only digits) should be': {
                $this->assertEquals(TRUE, $world['helper']->isId('123'));
            }
            case 'return of a string (containing not only digits) should be': {
                $this->assertEquals(FALSE, $world['helper']->isId('123abc-?'));
            }
            break;
            default: {
                return $this->notImplemented($action);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The only reference I'm using for BDD is [here](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/behaviour-driven-development.html), so there is much potential for improving this code.

Comment: Why you don't use [behat](http://behat.org/) with gherkins syntax? It's a PHP lib which is similar to Cucumber in Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your switch statements will run through until they find a break statement.  Having the braces {} only defines a block of code and has no effect on breaking out of the case.

```
switch (1)
{
case 1: {
   echo 'One';
}
case 2: {
   echo 'Two';
}
default: {
   echo 'Also default';
      }
}
```

The one above prints out "OneTwoAlso default" whereas the following prints out "One".

```
switch (1)
{
case 1:
   echo 'One';
   break;
case 2:
   echo 'Two';
   break;
default:
   echo 'Also default';
}
```

I think your testing would be cleaner if you didn't use `then` and `when` methods.  Normally I create an array of test data and expected results and loop over them.  As you are writing the test for the `isId` method I would have something like this:

```
public function test_isID()
{
   $object = new Object_That_You_Are_Testing();

   $tests = array(
      array('Data'            => 123,
            'Expected_Result' => true,
            'Test_Name'       => 'Positive Integer'),
      array('Data'            => -123,
            'Expected_Result' => false,
            'Test_Name'       => 'Negative Integer'));

   foreach ($tests as $test)
   {
      $this->assertEquals($test['Expected_Result'],
                          $object->isID($test['Data']),
                          $test['Test_Name'] . ' Failed');
   }
}
```

You could do more clever things than this.  Also a test will not always be so simple.  Normally I find that I have mocked objects and am ensuring that they get called appropriately.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this great idea - will try it when I'm writing next tests.